# "Persönliche Fehde" mit Nico

Tags: discussion, community-moderation, users

Da ich nicht weiß, wohin ich mich sonst wenden soll, schreibe ich das mal hierhin. Ich möchte mich an dieser Stelle offiziel über den Nutzer Nico beschweren. Nicht nur ist der Tonfall in vielen Kommentaren inakzeptabel (nicht nur mir gegenüber), es wird von ihm auch aus "Rache" downgevotet (was er in Kommentaren auch zugegeben hat). Das sollte zwar, wie üblich bei solchen Aktionen, sich von selbst wieder beheben, aber ich halte so einen Kindergarten hier trotzdem für absolut unangemessen.
Ich bin an dieser Stelle mit meinem Latein am Ende und suche daher Unterstützung von der Community, Mods oder Admins dieser ansonsten so netten Seite. Ich habe mehrfach versucht es mit ihm zu klären, worauf immer nur entgegnet wurde, er würde nicht mit mir diskutieren.

Comment: Dann diskutier doch nicht mit ihm. Ich mach das ja auch nicht. Irgendwann macht es gar keiner mehr und dann ist dieser Nutzer doch am Ziel seiner Wünsche angelangt.

Comment: Ist zwar traurig, aber wird wohl die Lösung sein.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis. Wir haben das bereits im Auge.

Comment: Namen zu nennen scheint hier mir nicht die beste Strategie zu sein. Um unparteiisch zu beurteilen, müsste man sich die Geschichte  anschauen. Dafür hat niemand Zeit. Dennoch habe ich leider schon im Hinterkopf die Idee, der Nico sei ganz böse, obwohl ich von ihm nichts las. Wie wäre es dann mit Anonymität?

Comment: Es ist nicht so, als wäre es ein Geheimnis.

Comment: Umso besser, dass es keins ist, dann wäre es jedem klar, worum es geht.

Comment: @c.p. In der Tat wäre Anonymität angesagt. Jemanden als Täter zu stilisieren, indem man sich als hilfloses Opfer darstellt, ist zunächst mal nicht sachlich und erinnert sehr an die antike Praktik der Sündenbocksuche. Aber jedem die Bühne, die er braucht...

Comment: Hier ist Ihre Chance ihr Verhalten zu erklären. Wenn Sie nicht jeden Versuch meinerseits abgelehnt hätten, hätte ich diesen Post auch nicht geschrieben. Anonymität sehr ich hier nicht als notwendig an, da alle Posts öffentlich sind/waren.

Comment: Fangen Sie erstmal an, Ihr Verhalten zu erklären und zu reflektieren! Ich bin nicht derjenige, der Hilfe gesucht hat. Ihrerseits gab es keine Versuche, die eine objektive Klärung signalisiert hätten. Das ist nicht das, was Sie wollen. Sie wollen provozieren und Konflikte schüren. Das ist auch unten in @olafants Antwort angedeutet, die sich auf Ihr Verhalten bezieht zu einer Zeit, zu der ich hier kein Mitglied war.

Comment: Nein, will ich nicht. Ich habe mehrfach geschrieben es sei nicht persönlich gemeint. Wenn ich einige Ihre Beiträge kritisiert habe, ging es um den Inhalt - nicht um Ihre Person. Wenn Sie dann antworten, dass es Sie nicht interessiere und Sie nicht mit mir diskutieren, dann bin ich etwas ratlos, welches Fehlverhalten Sie mir vorwerfen.

Comment: Ein Beispiel für das, was Sie als "Fehde" meinerseits bezeichnen: Ihr Kommentar zu einer meiner Antworten: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56404/why-do-we-use-the-same-word-bitte-for-please-and-you-are-welcome/56415#56415 "-1 as this just a hypothesis. See also this meta post [...] I find OP's hypothesis more convincing".  Ein Downvote, weil meine nur eine Hypothese war + Verweis darauf, dass Hypothesen nicht gefragt seien. Gleichzeitig aber "I find OP's hypothesis more convincing" und kein Downvote, obwohl Hypothesen nicht erwünscht sind. Wo ist da die Logik?

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht, dass ich das als Fehde bezeichnet hätte. Damit zitiere ich die Aussage eines anderen Nutzers, der sich über unsere ausufernden Kommentare beschwert hatte. OP stellt eine Frage, und äußert im Zuge dessen eine Vorstellung, für eine mögliche Begründung. Ich finde die Vorstellung plausibler als Ihre, gleichzeitig steht für beide Hypothesen eine Begründung aus. Ich hätte das Downvote auch vergeben, wenn ich Ihre Theorie für plausibler gehalten hätte.

Comment: 1) "Fehde" benutzen Sie in Ihrem OP, ohne zu kennzeichnen, dass es von jemand anderem kam. 2) "Ich hätte das Downvote auch vergeben, wenn ich Ihre Theorie für plausibler gehalten hätte"?? Logik? Entweder darf es keine Hypothesen geben oder doch!

Comment: Das ist doch genau das was ich sage. Ungeachtet von der Plausibilität der Hypothese bleibt es bei einer unbelegten Spekulation **in einer Antwort** und damit gebe ich ein Downvote ab. Das widerspricht nicht, dass man nicht eine Frage stellen darf, die eine Hypothese enthält. *Ich habe Hypothese X gehört. Ist da was dran oder ist es erfunden?*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104756/discussion-between-infinitezero-and-nico).

Comment: Einverstanden!!

Comment: Einladung zur Chatdiskussion und keine Antwort in der Chat!! Das sagt alles! Dann kommt eine Antwort a la "ich bin unterwegs und kann nicht schreiben" und gleichzeitig beantwortest -zig Fragen im Forum! So was Linkes habe ich noch nie erlebt!

Comment: Ich habe die Frage doch beantwortet. Sie dürfen schreiben, was Sie möchten. Danach kam nichts mehr.

Comment: Sag mal, geht es noch?? Du hast mich doch zum privaten Chatten eingeladen!! "Ich habe die Frage doch beantwortet. Sie dürfen schreiben, was Sie möchten. Danach kam nichts mehr". Wonach? Deinen Pusher hätte ich gerne!

Comment: Ich kann es gerne ein **drittes Mal** erklären. Die Chateinladungen sind dazu da,  nicht - wie jetzt hier schon wieder - die Kommentare mit Offtopic-Diskussion vollzuladen. Und genau da werde ich jetzt auch wieder antworten.

Comment: Nochmal: Wer hat mich zur Chatdiskussion eingeladen?

Comment: "Und genau da werde ich jetzt auch wieder antworten" Bier nach Feierabend ist super, aber nicht so, dass man so benebelt ist. Dir fehlt jegliche Logik!!

Comment: Aha! Also er verhält sich nicht nur auf ItalianSE so, sondern auch hier!

Comment: Mal schaun' was passiert. In ca. 3 Stunden ist der Gute wieder _im Geschäft_. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

In einer Hinsicht muss dir uneingeschränkt recht geben. Wenn mich eine Frage oder Antwort interessiert und ich mir deshalb die Kommentare durchlese, nervt es gewaltig, wenn unter jeder zweiten Frage eine Debatte darüber losgetreten wird, wer denn jetzt wem zuerst das Schäufelchen weggenommen hat. Das Wort Kindergarten kam auch mir da nicht erst einmal in den Sinn. Um dem eine Ende zu bereiten, gibt es eine einfache Lösung: einer von euch beiden (am besten beide) müsste einfach mal aufhören.

Ich werde hier weder für oder gegen dich noch für oder gegen andere Nutzer Partei ergreifen.

Da du aber fragst, kann ich aus meiner Sicht nur sagen, dass ihr beide keine Kinder von Traurigkeit seid. Als harmloses Beispiel will ich hier nur mal [deine Antwort](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1559/36196) (und die zugehörigen Kommentare) auf eine von mir gestellte Frage verlinken. Das könnte ich entweder als naive Unwissenheit oder aber als Provokation zum Zweck der Diskussion um der Diskussion willen interpretieren. Ob ich damit richtig liege oder nicht, spielt gar keine Rolle. Für beides ist mir meine Zeit zu schade und ich halte dann einfach den Mund. Das vielleicht als zur Nachahmung empfohlener Rat.

Plattformen wie diese haben es an sich, dass sich hier vor allem Leute tummeln, die gerne klugscheißen. Das ist völlig in Ordnung und ich nehme mich selbst da ausdrücklich nicht aus!

Aber man muss ja nicht alles stets und ständig und mit jedem ausdiskutieren. Insbesondere dann nicht, wenn absolut keine Aussicht auf Einigung besteht. Man muss auch nicht jedem seine Meinung aufdrängen und man muss auch nicht zu jedem und allem stets und ständig seinen Senf dazu geben und vor allem muss man auch nicht auf Biegen und Brechen immer recht behalten wollen.

Eure persönlichen Zu- und Abneigungen interessieren mich wenig bis gar nicht. Deshalb will ich das auch nicht ständig lesen müssen. Wenn ihr euch nicht leiden könnt, geht euch einfach aus dem Weg. Das ist überhaupt nicht traurig. Das ist hier keine Kuschelgruppe und wir müssen uns auch nicht alle lieb haben. Allerdings gebe ich dir auch damit recht, dass man in der Kommunikation mit erwachsenen Menschen einen gewissen Grad an Höflichkeit und respektvoller Zurückhaltung mit persönlichen Be- und Empfindlichkeiten erwarten kann, *insbesondere* dann, wenn man sich wenig sympathisch ist.

Ansonsten weiß ich nicht, welche Art von Unterstützung du hier erwartest. Es kann wohl kaum darum gehen, hier einzelne Nutzer öffentlich an den Pranger zu stellen und sich dann gemeinsam auf sie einzuschießen. Insofern finde ich auch den Kommentar *Wir haben das bereits im Auge.* ziemlich daneben.

Wenn du an dich gerichtete Kommentare als beleidigend oder in irgend einer Art übergriffig findest, nutze die flag-Funktion. Dazu ist sie da. Das kann jeder andere Nutzer auch für an ihn gerichtete Kommentare tun, falls er es für erforderlich hält. Falls die Moderatoren Handlungsbedarf sehen, werden sie - denke ich - ihnen als angemessen erscheinende Maßnahmen ergreifen.

Vielleicht - und das richtet sich nicht speziell an dich - können wir einfach mal wieder auf den Boden der Fragen und Antworten zu sprachlichen Themen zurückkehren und Bevormundungen, Belehrungen, Erziehungsversuche und Schuldzuweisungen weglassen. *Wer* hier eine Frage stellt oder beantwortet, spielt überhaupt keine Rolle. Wer hier was und warum up- oder downvotet, ist ganz allein jedem selbst überlassen. Und wer Beziehungsdramen braucht, wende sich doch bitte an seinen Freundes- und Familienkreis.

Zum Abschluss vielleicht noch dieses Zitat aus dem [Code of Conduct](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct):

> If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

Comment: Gute Antwort (+1)!

Comment: "Insofern finde ich auch den Kommentar *Wir haben das bereits im Auge.* ziemlich daneben" - gutes Beispiel, wie unterschiedlich man interpretieren kann: ich hatte Takkats Kommentar als "Wir Mods haben die Auseinandersetzungen bemerkt und beobachten/intervenieren bei Bedarf" verstanden, ohne dass dabei Partei ergriffen wurde. Ansonsten 100% Zustimmung zu Deiner Antwort! :)

Comment: @Arsak: deine Interpretation ist ganz richtig.

Comment: @Arsak OP sagt, *ich möchte mich über ... beschweren, weil ...*. Da finde ich die Formulierung *Wir haben das bereits im Auge* sehr unglücklich gewählt. Ich gehe davon aus, dass der Kommentar so gemeint war, wie du es hier m.E. wunderbar *übersetzt* und Takkat bestätigt das ja auch noch einmal.

Comment: @Olafant Ich habe mich bisher enthalten, weil ich deine Bemerkungen voll "on spot" finde. Ich möchte aber jetzt Fakten darlegen.Takkats Aussage oben ist unwahr. Ein paar Stunden nachdem das Posting erschienen war, bekam ich eine  Ermahnung, ohne dass Weiteres vorgefallen wäre. Insofern stimmt deine Vermutung: "Wir haben das bereits im Auge" bedeutete "Wir haben Nico im Auge". Ich reagierte mit einer Antwort, in der ich meinen z.T. unsachlichen Ton problemlos zugab. Ich bat die Moderation auch darum, die zwei Seiten des Konfliktes zu berücksichtigen, erhielt allerdings keine Antwort.

Comment: @Takkat Nein, die Interpretation ist FAKTISCH unwahr!

Comment: @Nico: Woher das Wissen, dass sich keiner aus dem Moderatoren-Team an keinen anderen gewendet hat? Es klingt immer so "faktisch allwissend", das irritiert mich, weil dem eigentlich nie so sein kann. Zumal ich "ein paar Stunden nachdem" verstehe als: nix automatischer Reflex gegen nur einen. Die Einsicht in "meinen z.T. unsachlichen Ton" sehe ich als Chance, dass künftig einer mehr sich um Sachlichkeit bemüht. Wenn ich jetzt noch das Gefühl verliere, dass jegliche Anschuldigungen egozentrisch ("alle gegen mich Neuen") sein sollen, dann hab ich das Gefühl von "passd scho". Meine subjektive Sicht

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Ich habe nur die Fakten dargelegt, die ich kenne. "Alle gegen mich Neuen" habe ich nie behauptet. Habe oft hier (Meta) geschrieben, dass ich mich NICHT als Opfer sehe. Zudem muss ich festhalten, dass ich deine moralisierende Intervention "sehe ich als Chance, dass künftig einer mehr sich um Sachlichkeit bemüht" hier vollkommen übergreifend und fehl am Platz finde.

Comment: @Nico: Ich beziehe mich hier nur auf die Kommentare in diesem Thread. Tut mir leid für die "moralisierende Intervention" - es ist meine Schlussfolgerung aus `meinen z.T. unsachlichen Ton problemlos zugab`. Das klingt für mich wie eine Entschuldigung der Form "war Mist, werde ich besser machen". Die Passage `Insofern stimmt deine Vermutung: "Wir haben das bereits im Auge" bedeutete "Wir haben Nico im Auge".` wiederum las ich als "nur ich bin der Schuldige". Nun, dann werde ich sehen, was die Zukunft bringt. Schönen Tag.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Hier muss wohl ein Missverständnis vorliegen. "Wir haben das bereits im Auge" bedeutet für mich nicht "wir schicken eine Ermahnung" (es sei denn, es passiert Weiteres, was uns dazu veranlasst). Wenn jemand zugibt, einen unangebrachten Ton verwendet zu haben, bedarf es m.E. nicht eines Kommentars a la "jetzt ziehste vielleicht mal 'ne Lehre daraus". So was nenne ich schlichtweg "eindreschen"

Answer (score 3):

## Aus den Memoiren eines Streithansels

Ich bin, glaube ich, auch als eher streitlustig bekannt. Soviele Downvotes wie ich (> 2000) hat hier m.W. niemand verteilt. Dennoch bin ich in 20 Jahren (oder sind es 9?) noch nicht gesperrt worden. Was mache ich richtig?

A) Jede Diskussion beginnt bei Null. Es zählt nur, was der andere in dieser Diskussion sagt, nicht was er letzte Woche bei einem anderen Topic geschrieben hat. Er kann sich geändert haben und ich erwarte auch von anderen, dass sie auf meinen aktuellen Beitrag eingehen, nicht auf Sachen von JWD und anno tobak, die unbeteiligte Dritte, die mitlesen, wahrscheinlich nicht auf dem Schirm haben. Zu Hilfe kommt mir hier ein schlechtes Namensgedächtnis - ich kann mir eh nicht merken, wer immer wieder die gleichen Fehler macht.

B) Niemals ad hominem gehen. Persönliche Angriffe nicht persönlich kontern. Entweder man flaggt es oder man ignoriert es. Gewaltmonopol des Staates, bzw. hier: der Mods.

C) Doppelt prüfen, ob man Recht hat. Es ist so peinlich, wenn man sich aufgeplustert hat, und dann jmd. die Luft rauslässt.

D) Bei echter Wut, drüber schlafen. Dann trotzdem kontern, aber eben besonders sachlich. Wenn es sich erhitzt nur einen Konter pro Tag - wichtige Fragen haben Zeit. Oft kühlt es sich wieder ab, vielleicht auch, weil man die Gegenseite mit in diesen Takt zwingt und die sich nach 3 Tagen zu beruhigen beginnt.

E) Nicht klein beigeben, wenn man Recht hat. Das nährt den Groll. Auf das Konto "bei dem hab ich noch einen gut wegen ..." gibt's keine Zinsen, es kauft einem keiner ab. Recht kann man nicht ansparen.

F) Den Konfliktpunkt möglichst eng und präzise herausarbeiten.

G) Inhaltliche Kritik ist eine besondere Form der Würdigung. Nachdenken und Selbstbeherrschung. Das beste Argument leidet, wenn man zu Beschimpfungen und Schmähungen abgleitet. Man bringt nur die Autoritäten gegen sich auf.

H) Sich angewöhnen zu lesen was geschrieben wurde, ohne auf den Nick/Avatar zu achten. Man setzt sich mit Argumenten auseinander, nicht mit denen die sie äußern. Arschlöcher können gute Argumente und in einer Sache Recht haben. Nette, liebe Leute reden oft Unfug. Sehr oft. Leider.

I) Wenn man sicher weiß, die Argumentation wird nix bringen, auch Dritten nicht: Downvote, anonym. Bekennerschreiben sind nicht verpflichtend.

J) Im Havariefall, beim GAU, man hatte selbst unrecht: Unrecht einräumen. Kann jedem passieren, ist mir auch schon passiert (1978).